# Another way to say "A weirdo who always solve math problem"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, nouns, synonyms, epithet-requests

Just like the tittle, I want to ask you guys how to say the sentence in a different way. My full sentence is "Back then, I was often seen as a weirdo who always solved math problems". That's pretty much what I mean. But is there any other way I can make it sound better?

Any different way will do because it seems to me that "solved math problems" is kind of long and basic. So I want to embellish it a little but I can't figure out the way. A noun would be best, but I want to seek for different opinions as well.

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: @curious-proofreader Any different way will do because it seems to me that "solved math problems" is kind of long and basic. So I want to embellish it a little but I can't figure out the way. A noun would be best, but I want to seek for different opinions as well. Thanks :D

Comment: Some actual context would be good. In what context are you trying to convey what meaning? Employment? CV? Casual talk with friends etc.? However, I'd simply go with "affinity for math" or similar instead of "solve math problems" as that just speaks to interest and ability.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thanks a lot. The sentence is for an essay where I tell a story about how I has transformed myself into a more confident and independent person. So the sentence is in the first part of the story when I was just "a weirdo who always solved math problems".

Comment: For an essay about life story - I actually find it perfectly fine to use your original sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of ways to write your sentence.  The existing suggestions of nerd, brainiac or boringly studious may be see as slightly pejorative terms so I reckon something like the following may be more palatable:

**"I was more engaged by my maths work than by socialising"**

or
**"I used to focus almost exclusively on maths but recently I've worked on becoming a more rounded person"**

or
**"Maths used to be my whole life but now I have more interests"**

etc...

Comment: This is incredibly suitable with the scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*a math **nerd***

> Back then, I was often seen as a math nerd.

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nerd):

> nerd  (also nurd) *NOUN*
>
> *informal*
>   **1A** foolish or contemptible person who lacks social skills or is **boringly studious**:
>   *I was a serious nerd until I discovered girls and cars*
>
> **1.1** A single-minded expert in a particular technical field:
>   *a computer nerd*

Comment: You could also say "math geek" which has less negative connotations ("nerd" implies poor social skills while "geek" implies "an unfashionable enthusiam")

Comment: Yes, I thought of geek too; however, I found it bit positive (as you rightly said) for a _wierdo_.

Comment: How I thought "weirdo" was such a cute word...

Comment: @steven, I still think it's a cute word.

Comment: @MaxWilliams just stole my plan of answer...: [Math geek](https://www.amazon.com/Math-Geek-Nerdiest-Theorems-Equations/dp/1440583811).

Answer (score 0):

"Back then, I was often seen as a math brainiac." 
"Back then, I was often seen as a brainiac with a proclivity for math."

Comment: "brainiac" as I searched is "an exceptionally intelligent person". Is it too much ? By the way, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is often used as an insult as well, much like how the other answer used "nerd". Though I believe it is more playful than that and could fit a self referential tone like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is boring and excessively studious as well is referred to as a **poindexter**. [**OED**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poindexter)

> A boringly studious and socially inept person.